# How to figure out why a process is stuck

Tags: process

I am doing large DB imports on a Postgres instance running in a Proxmox 1.9 OpenVZ virtualized Ubuntu 11.04. For some reason, the executable that initiates and controls the import (or Postgres), always stops at some point, typically, when there is high I/O load on the system (i.e. the proxmox host or in any of the VM instances) caused in addition to that of the importing process. I am trying to figure out the root issue and whether I can potentially avoid it.
Ps tells me that wchan = n_tty_ for the importing process (which is sleeping). First of all what does this mean and what are good practices in how to debug further?

Answer (score 4):

Try strace.

You can invoke it like *strace -p pid*

Or, better yet, *strace your_prog_here*

Comment: strace -f -v -p 27662
    Process 27662 attached - interrupt to quit
    read(0, Process 27662 attached - interrupt to quit  
    read(0,
    ^C <unfinished ...>
    Process 27662 detached'
Hm, I am not any wiser now..

Comment: file descriptor 0 is stdin, it sounds like this process is reading something from it's terminal or a pipe, and it is waiting for that.  Are you sure you are running the command properly (passing input to it on stdin when necessary)?  Is there a command in a pipe in front of this that maybe is hanging and not sending data to this process?

Comment: The program is a c program compiled on the same system and it talks to postgres via pipe, so this could be the issue here I guess (it does not require user intervention).
Postgres indicates the program still as connected, though idle for more than 24hs. To me, this looks like a problem with IPC.
As I have the source of the c program (I am not not a c developer, though), is it maybe possible (and would it help) to include some kind of debug symbols/compile it with debug flags (without changing the source and with gcc) that could provide more information?